# Клавиши вниз/вверх в библиотеке turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle

Работаю с библиотекой **turtle**.
Мне нужно задать бинд клавиши на стрелки вниз и вверх.
Как они называются в Python?
И где вообще все клавиши можно глянуть?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Метод [turtle.onkey(fun, key)](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkey) отслеживает нажатие клавиш:

```
>>> def f():
...     fd(50)
...     lt(60)
...
>>> screen.onkey(f, "Up")
>>> screen.listen()
```

Курсорные клавиши вверх/вниз - "Up" и "Down", соответственно.
PS Смотреть правильнее и лучше всего в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#) к библиотеке.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
def fd():
    fd(50)

listen()
onkey(fd(), "Up")
```

Comment: `onkey(fd(), "Up")` - вот эта строка сразу вызывает функцию fd, результат передает в onkey (а не передает саму функцию в onkey). Но до возврата результата дело не дойдет, потому что функция внутри пытается вызвать сама себя, причем с параметром, а параметров у нее нет, поэтому упадет с ошибкой типизации.

Comment: Ну и подозреваю, что listen() не передает управление ниже себя, пока существует окно. В любом случае, этот вариант не выглядит рабочим.